# use PUT to generate unique identifier and upload file

Tags: rest, http, post, put

I have a requirement to upload a file using REST APIs.
I was going through some of the tutorials and understood that POST is for creating new resource and PUT is to create/update a resource.

I have to upload a file and generate some unique identifier(url) for the same.
One way is to a) use POST to generate a new url and b) use the same url to upload file using PUT.
But is it possible to combine both these steps into one using PUT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally you just POST the file and the result of that is the unique identifier. Why would you need a two-stage process?

Comment: Your single POST operation can do both these i.,e file processing (if needed) and can return the unique ID of the uploaded file

Comment: great, thanks a lot, can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

1. If the client decides what URI is going to be used, use `PUT`.
2. If the server has to decide the URI, use `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use POST to create the domain resource (with file as request body) and return 201 location header with created resource uri. Doing it as a single POST is perfectly fine. Refer https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location